# Prove that $|x|<|y| \iff x^2<y^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

My proof is below. I am not sure about the second part.
Proof:
First I prove $|x|<|y| \implies x^2<y^2$.
Suppose $|x|<|y|$. Then,
\begin{align*}
|x||x| < |y||x| &\implies x^2<|y||x|\tag1\\
|y||x| < |y||y| &\implies |y||x| < y^2\tag2 
\end{align*}
By $(1)$ and $(2)$, $x^2<y^2$
Next I prove $x^2<y^2 \implies |x|<|y|$. For that consider the contrapositive.
$$|x| \geq |y| \implies x^2 \geq y^2$$
From previous case $|x|>|y| \implies x^2>y^2$ is true. Therefore the contrapositive is true. Hence the result follows.

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: Yes.... the proof is correct.

Comment: Oh,, wait.  Actually have to consider what happens if $|x| = |y|$.  You didn't take that into account.

Comment: There's another problem with (1). You should also consider the case where $|x| = 0$. Really, in (1), you should be concluding $x^2 \le |y||x|$.

Comment: Eep.  I guess your proof *isn't* correct after all.   You do need to *state* that both $|x|$ and $|y|$ are $>0$ and you have to consider the case were $|x| = 0$.  And in the contrapositive you must consider thatn if $|x|\not < |y|$ so $|x| \ge |y|$ that *either* $|x| > |y|$ *OR* $|x| = |y|$ and show both of those show that $x^2 < y^2$ is not true.

Comment: Note that if $x^2 < y^2 $ (which means $y^2>0$) then $(|{ x\over y }|)^2 < 1$. Since $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is strictly increasing and evaluates to $1$ for $x=1$ we see that $|{x\over y }| < 1$ and hence $|x| < |y|$.

Comment: Don't you know that $x\mapsto x^2$ and $\sqrt x$ are strictly oncreasing on $[0,\infty )$ ?

Comment: @fleablood I understand you, But another problem arose in my mind. Although both $A$ and $B$ are false, the statement $A \implies B$ is true. Isn't it ? So when considering $|x|=0$ in $(1)$ both $A$ and $B$ are wrong. But the statement is correct. So should I consider that case ? Next, since $|x|<|y|$ is assumed in the first part, should I consider the case $|x|=|y| ?$

Comment: @Nimantha It is possible for $|x| = 0$, and $A$ and $B$ to be both right; you might be thinking of the $|y| = 0$ possibility? If $|y| = 0$, then indeed both $A$ and $B$ are false. You don't have to explicitly worry about this case; just note that $0 \le |x| < |y|$, so $0 < |y|$.

Comment: "So when considering |x|=0 in (1) both A and B are wrong"  Why do you say that?  If $|x|=0 < |y|$ is perfectly plausible.  And as a result it *will* be true that $x^2 <y^2$ but your proof that $|x||x| < |x||y|$ is not valid and not true ($|x||x|\not < |x||y|$... $|x||x|=|x||y|$).  If $|x| = 0$ then $x^2=0$ and $|y|> |x|=0$ then $|y|>0$ and $y^2 =|y||y|> 0 = x^2$.

Comment: And in the contrapositive.  The contrapositive of $x^2 < y^2 \implies |x| < |y|$ is $|x|\ge |y| \ge x^2 \ge y^2$.  So you must consider if $|x| = |y|$ (in which case $x^2 = y^2$ and so $x^2 \ge y^2$) and consider if $|x|>|y|$ (in which case $x^2 > y^2$ and so $x^2 \ge y^2$).  Both cases must be considered.